# How to JSON.stringify a dom element?

Tags: javascript, dom

As title , how to JSON.stringify a dom element, and change back the json to a dom element.

Any one know how to do , thanks.

```
Here is the code :
var container = document.querySelectorAll('.container')
 var json=JSON.stringify(container)
 {"0":{},"1":{},"2":{},"3":{}}"//result

  expected result:
  {"tagname":"div","class":"container","value":"test","childelement":[...]}
```

Comment: Are you trying to store the HTML markup or the `HTMLElement` object as `JSON`?

Comment: Can you include HTML and expected result at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why would you JSON.stringify it, just use its outerHTML value.

Comment: Hi guest271314, yes , i want to change HTMLElement to JSON Format,Thanks.

Comment: Hi guest271314, i have update the code ,thanks.

Comment: Hi ibrahim mahrir, i need the tagname ,id or class as key ... ,not only outerHTML,Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to store functions and event listeners as well? What should occur when `ownderDocument` property is reached?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the most reasonable approach would be to whitelist which properties of the DOM element you want to serialize:

```
JSON.stringify(container, ["id", "className", "tagName"])
```

The second parameter of the `JSON.stringify` function allows you to change the behavior of the stringification process. You can specify an array with the list of properties to serialize. More information here: [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

If you want to serialize its child nodes too, some extra work is needed. In this case you will have to specify a replacer function as the second parameter of `JSON.stringify`, instead of an array.

```
let whitelist = ["id", "tagName", "className", "childNodes"];
function domToObj (domEl) {
    var obj = {};
    for (let i=0; i<whitelist.length; i++) {
        if (domEl[whitelist[i]] instanceof NodeList) {
            obj[whitelist[i]] = Array.from(domEl[whitelist[i]]);
        }
        else {
            obj[whitelist[i]] = domEl[whitelist[i]];
        }
    };
    return obj;
}

JSON.stringify(container, function (name, value) {
    if (name === "") {
        return domToObj(value);
    }
    if (Array.isArray(this)) {
        if (typeof value === "object") {
            return domToObj(value);
        }
        return value;
    }
    if (whitelist.find(x => (x === name)))
        return value;
})
```

The replacer function transforms the hosted objects in `childNodes` to native objects, that `JSON.stringify` knows how to serialize. The `whitelist` array has the list of properties to serialize. You can add your own properties here.

Some extra work in the replacer function might be needed if you want to serialize other properties that reference hosted objects (for example, `firstChild`).

Comment: Hi ncardeli , how about if have a child element?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to serialize child nodes too.

Answer (score 7):

I wondered the same thing, and I appreciate the answer from @ncardeli. In my app, I needed something a little different, and I thought I'd share in case anyone is interested. It recursively displays properties of any children too.

Press the button below to run the example. You can add whatever properties you want to obj and therefore to the result.

```js
function showStringifyResult(target) {
  let result = document.getElementById("result");
  result.select();
  result.setRangeText(JSON.stringify(stringify(target), null, ' '));
}

function stringify(element) {
  let obj = {};
  obj.name = element.localName;
  obj.attributes = [];
  obj.children = [];
  Array.from(element.attributes).forEach(a => {
    obj.attributes.push({ name: a.name, value: a.value });
  });
  Array.from(element.children).forEach(c => {
    obj.children.push(stringify(c));
  });
  
  return obj;
}
```

```css
#list {
  margin-top: 18px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Press the Stringify button to write the stringified object to the textarea below.
</h1>

<button onClick="showStringifyResult(document.body)" class="c1">
  Stringify
</button>

<div id="list">
  A list for example:
  <ul class="first second">
    <li id="First Item">Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li class="inactive">Item 3</li>
    <li data-tag="tag">Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<textarea id="result" cols="200" rows="20" ></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, this was exactly what I needed to export the entire DOM from `WKWebView .evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)` for further processing.

Comment: Silly question but JSON.parse will return the DOM element correctly I believe

Answer (score 3):

Old question but anyhow, I was in the same situation, when you have access to the element you need and you just want the html of it and it's children. Turned out all one needs to do is to grab the content of the outerHTML property on the DOM object. This gives you a string, which you could put into a JSON as a value or not.

`let HTML = container.outerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is an old thread here is my addition:

`JSON.stringify(target, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target["__proto__"]), 2)`

Give you a quick list for some of the properties of the DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can stringify a DOM node:

```js
const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
const text = serializer.serializeToString(document.body);
console.log(text);
```

If you need to serialize only the visible nodes to JSON object, here is how you can do it using Typescript:

```js
interface NodeElement {
  name: string;
  attributes: Record<string, any>;
  children: Array<NodeElement | string>;
}

function serializeDOMToJson(element: Element) {
  function serializeNode(node: ChildNode) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      
      const attributes: Record<string, any> = {};
      for (const attr of (node as Element).attributes) {
        attributes[attr.name] = attr.value;
      }

      const children: Array<any> = [];
      node.childNodes.forEach(child => {
        const serializedChild = serializeNode(child);
        if (serializedChild) children.push(serializedChild);
      });

      const obj: NodeElement = {
        name: (node as Element).tagName.toLowerCase(),
        attributes,
        children,
      };

      return obj;
    } else if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && (node as any).nodeValue.trim()) {
      return node.nodeValue;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  return serializeNode(element);
}

const tree = serializeDOMToJson(document.body);
console.log(tree);
```