# How to generate array into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

So, basically I have page with images (with like button for each of them), which should be displayed on another page, after the button is clicked.

This is how I get the images (after their button is being clicked) into array:

```
$('button').click(e => {
    let likedImgs= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart') || '[]');
    let itemName = $(e.target).data('name');
    let item = $('img').filter(v => v.name === itemName);

    likedImgs.push(item);
    localStorage.setItem('likedImgs', JSON.stringify(likedImgs));

});
```

On the page with liked photos I have:

```
 <template>
                        <div id="isOutput"></div>
                </template>
```

And this is how I try to generate the array into HTML and display it as an image on the next page:

```
  var myArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('likedImgs'));
                function  showContent () {
                  var temp, item, a, i;
                  temp = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0];
                  item = temp.content.querySelector("div");
                  for (i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
                    a = document.importNode(item, true);
                    a.textContent += myArr[i];
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                  }
                }
```

But this doesn`t seem to work. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

The console gives back array of objects which look like this :  0: prevObject: 0: {} 1: {} 2: {} 3: {} 4: {} 5: {} 6: {} length: 7 prevObject: {0: {…}, length: 1} proto: Object proto: Object

Comment: what do you mean, "this doesn't seem to work"? And are you actually calling the `showContent` function anywhere?

Comment: You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to include all relevant code in a snippet that's runnable on SO, in a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, I am calling the function, but it display it as [object Object], not as an image, that`s why I am asking what am I doing wrong when I generate the array into an HTML.

Comment: Can you paste a sample of what `myArr` Looks like ? Is it an array of objects ? Array of strings etc ?

Comment: It is array of objects

Comment: You're pushing a jQuery object (`item`) into `likedImgs`. Serializing a jQuery object rarely works well, since DOM Elements don't serialize.

Comment: If its an array of objects, then the line `a.textContent += myArr[i];` is incorrect. It  will show `[Object object]`. Please update the question with the array values so that we can give the proper way to do it.

Comment: please put the result array in the question not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

`stringify()` does not handle DOM elements very well.

> [Related Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46881092/903014): How to JSON.stringify a dom element?

As a result we need to pull the attributes we want out of the images and stringify them.

In this example, I am using a hidden input to act like local storage for simplicity.

On the button click we just parse the hidden field, and recreate the elements in the `result` area

```js
let likedImgs = [];
let itemName = '1'; //$(e.target).data('name');
let item = $('#source > img').filter((i, v) => v.name !== itemName); //changed the filter for demonstration
//only 'stringify' the properties that matter to me
likedImgs = $.map(item, x => {
  return {
    src: $(x).attr("src"),
    name: $(x).attr("name")
  };
});
//store them somewhere for example instead of localStorage//
$("#tst").val(JSON.stringify(likedImgs)); //replace with storing in localStorage
//localStorage.setItem('likedImgs', JSON.stringify(likedImgs));
//console.log($("#tst").val()); //output for prosperity



//handle a button click just for fun
$("button#p").click(x => show($("#tst").val())); //you will need to read from localStorage instead
//$("button#p").click(x => show(localStorage.getItem('likedImgs')));//like this

//process a json string, this function to be on page 2
function show(txt) {
  var txt = JSON.parse(txt);
  //var txt = JSON.parse(txt);
  var tmplate = $("#result");
  tmplate.empty(); //clean out the results//
  $.each(txt, function(i, elem) {
    tmplate.append($("<img>")
      .attr("src", elem.src)
      .attr("name", elem.name));
  });
}
```

```css
div#source>img {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
}

div#result>img {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='p'>Process</button>
<div id='source'>
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random' name="1" />
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random' name="2" />
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random' name="3" />
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random' name="4" />
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random' name="5" />
</div>
<input id='tst' type='hidden' />
<!-- placeholder for localStorage -->
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Hello, Steve,

Thanks for your answer, it works but when the images appear on the same page. How can I make them to appear on another page, after the button is being clicked?

Comment: This is just a sample that I can do in a stack-snippet.  the hidden field represents your localStorage replace it with that.  Read it from the next page